# Ergodicity vs Weak Mixing

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I have been trying to prove the following:

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space endowed with probability measure $\mathbb{P}$. Suppose $\tau : \Omega \to \Omega$ is a measure preserving transform, i.e. $\forall A \in \mathcal{F}$, $\mathbb{P}(\tau^{-1}A) = \mathbb{P}(A)$.

Prove that $\tau$-ergodic iff for any measurable $A,B$
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \mathbb{P}[A \cap \tau^{-k}B] \rightarrow \mathbb{P}[A] \mathbb{P}[B]
\end{equation}

Above, $\tau$-ergodic means for every $E$ with property $E = \tau^{-1}E$, $\mathbb{P}[E] = 0 $ or $1$.

I have proved that if the given claim (a.k.a weak mixing) holds, then $\tau$ is indeed ergodic. However, I failed to prove the other direction, I did it when $A$ is a $\tau$-invariant event but could not extend to the general case. I am not %100 sure whether the statement is correct. Any proof or counterexample? Any help is appreciated.

PS: Sorry if something is wrong with my notation, I am very new into Ergodic theory.

Comment: Yes, the forward direction is true. It is a special case of the well-known [Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory#Probabilistic_formulation:_Birkhoff.E2.80.93Khinchin_theorem) and can be deduced from it via the dominated convergence theorem. However, I think you are supposed to give a proof from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

First let me note that weak mixing is something different, in fact stronger than ergodicity.

For the other direction note that
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B)
&=\mathbb P(A)\int_\Omega 1_B\,d\mathbb P\\
&=\int_\Omega\mathbb P(A)1_B\,d\mathbb P\\
&=\int_\Omega\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1_A\circ \tau^k) 1_B\,d\mathbb P\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_\Omega 1_{\tau^{-k}A\cap B}\,d\mathbb P,
\end{split}
$$
using dominated convergence in the last identity. Therefore,
$$
\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\mathbb P(\tau^{-k}A\cap B).
$$